# Powershell and ClickHouse

Tags: powershell, clickhouse

I'm trying to configure Powershell as ETL and want to fetch data from ClickHouse, can anyone suggest an example of connecting to a database for Powershell? Or is there no way to do it? Through ODBC, requests hang tight, even `Select 1`.

```bsh
$Cnn = new-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection("DSN=test"); 
$Cnn.Open() 
$CmdCreate = $Cnn.CreateCommand() 
$CmdCreate.CommandText = " select 1" 
$CmdCreate.ExecuteNonQuery() # | Out-Null $Cnn.Close()
```

Comment: could you provide that all you have done - ODBC config file, powershell script, etc. ?

Comment: ODBC registered port, address, user and password. There are no problems with this, everything works. In PS I try to do this:                                                                               
        $Cnn = new-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection("DSN=test");
 $Cnn.Open()
 $CmdCreate = $Cnn.CreateCommand()
 $DWHCmdCreate.CommandText = "

select 1"

 $CmdCreate.ExecuteNonQuery() # | Out-Null
       
       $Cnn.Close()    
and it timeout, maybe you can do it not through ODBC? Use ClickHouse Driver?

Comment: follow this article to configure and check ODBC connection to ClickHouse: [CONNECTING EXCEL TO CLICKHOUSE USING THE WINDOWS ODBC DRIVER](https://altinity.com/blog/connecting-excel-to-clickhouse-using-the-windows-odbc-driver)

Comment: I have no problems with ODBC connection, I am looking for alternative ways. Everything is configured correctly, there is a question why there is a timeout, but this is not the problem. The question is how you can get data from ClickHouse other than ODBC using PowerShell

Comment: Consider using HTTP-endpoint - https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/

Comment: I run your code on my Windows-infrastructure and it worked fine for 64-bits ODBC driver. Try to turn on and check ODBC logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alternate ODBC can be used [ClickHouse HTTP interface](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/):

```bsh
$Env:clickhouse_server = '1.1.1.1'
$Env:user = 'user'
$Env:password = 'passw'

# pass credentials in URL
('SELECT version()' `
  | Invoke-WebRequest "http://${Env:clickhouse_server}:8123?user=${Env:user}&password=${Env:password}" `
  -Method 'POST' -UseBasicParsing).Content

# pass credentials in Headers
('SELECT version()' `
  | Invoke-WebRequest "http://${Env:clickhouse_server}:8123" `
  -Headers @{'X-ClickHouse-User'="${Env:user}"; 'X-ClickHouse-Key'="${Env:password}"} `
  -Method 'POST' -UseBasicParsing).Content
```

---

Consider using *python* to access CH (see [clickhouse_driver](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)):

```bsh
pip install clickhouse-driver

python
>>> from clickhouse_driver import Client
>>> import os
>>> client = Client(host=os.getenv('clickhouse_server'), user=os.getenv('user'), password=os.getenv('password'))
>>> client.execute('SELECT version()')
[('20.3.12.112',)]
>>>
```